# Save and Load multiple dataframes from one CSV

Tags: r, csv, dataframe

How can I save 3 dataframes of different dimensions to one csv in order to load them afterwards in 3 different dataframes?

E.g

```
write.table(A, file = "di2.csv", row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, sep=',')
write.table(B, file = "di2.csv", row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, sep=',', append=TRUE)
write.table(C, file = "di2.csv", row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, sep=',', append=TRUE)
```

or in a more elegant way

```
write.csv(rbind(A, B, C), "di2.csv")
```

How can I load this `CSV` to 3 dataframes, A,B and C?

Comment: How would R know which rows to put into which data.frame? Since you wrote one file, it's easiest to read it in to one data.frame and split it as needed. Otherwise if you really need to you can use combinations of `skip=` and `nrows=` to read certain lines from the file (but somehow you'd have to know where the split needs to happen ahead of time).

Comment: Its easy to guess that one needs to pass some kind of information in order to load it afterwards. Can you suggest how to save those dataframes if later I can load them safely?

Comment: If you don't need it to be in CSV format, and you just need to re-load it into R later, use `save()/load()` to save multiple R objects to a file.

Comment: Is it possible for one to convert that saved R object to csv aftwerwards? please provide an example @MrFlick to accept your answer :)

Comment: The `?save/?load` help pages provide examples. Once you've loaded the data.frame back into R, you can use `write.csv` as normal.

Comment: I know my friend, I already used your advice and it works
 `save(A_table, B_table,  file="temp.Rdata")`
 `load("temp.Rdata")`
I'm just saying since you helped me just post it in order to close it

Comment: Feel free to post your own answer for what worked for you. I don't need the points. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments if your purpose is just to read them back into R later then you could use save/load.

Another simple solution is dump/source:

```
A <- B <- C <- BOD # test input
dump(c("A", "B", "C"))

# read back
source("dumpdata.R")
```

Other multiple object formats that you could consider would be hdf and an SQLite database (which is a single file).

On the other hand if it is important that it be readable text, directly readable by Excel and at least somewhat similar to a csv file then write the data frames out one after another with a blank line after each.  Then to read them back later, read the file and separate the input at the blank lines. `st` and `en` are the starting and ending line numbers of the chunks in `Lines`.

```
A <- B <- C <- BOD # test inputs

# write data frames to a single file
con <- file("out.csv", "w")
for(el in list(A, B, C)) {
   write.csv(el, con, row.names = FALSE)
   writeLines("", con)
}
close(con)

# read data.frames from file into a list L
Lines <- readLines("out.csv")
en <- which(Lines == "")
st <- c(1, head(en, -1))
L <- Map(function(st, en) read.csv(text = Lines[st:en]), st, en)
```

Note that there are some similarities between this question and [Importing from CSV from a specified range of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47141541/importing-from-csv-from-a-specified-range-of-values/47142288#47142288)

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
save(A_table, B_table, C_table, file="temp.Rdata") 
load("temp.Rdata")
```